# How should I make the entry point of angular to a .jsp file rather than index.html?

Tags: angular, jsp

I want the initial startup of the file to be an .jsp file rather than index.html.

My angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "secondpageapp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/secondpageapp",
            "index": "src/index.jsp",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "secondpageapp:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "secondpageapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "secondpageapp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "secondpageapp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "secondpageapp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "secondpageapp"
}
```

My index.jsp:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="..\node_modules\@angular\common\bundles\common.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="..\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="..\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js"></script>
    <script src="..\node_modules\reflect-metadata\Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="..\node_modules\rxjs\bundles\rxjs.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="..\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser\bundles\platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="..\node_modules\@angular\platform-browser-dynamic\bundles\platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>

    <title>First JSP</title>

</head>

<body>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII" pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>

    <h3>Hi Pankaj</h3><br>
    <strong>Current Time is</strong>:
    <% out.print("Welcome"); %>
    <app-root>

    </app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

The method of including the jsp page inside the index.html will not work as the requirements are different. Please help me with using the jsp page as my entry point for the angular application.

Comment: You run `ng build --prod`, then you copy all the content of the generated index.html file and you paste it into your JSP? But seriously, why?

Comment: actually, I am moving a project from AngularJS to Angular 8. So since the conversion will take time and development can't stop. Trying to make a hybrid model without disturbing much of the earlier code.